# how to create ActiveRecord::Base object for non-model table in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table named `financial_details` I want to alter the table by dropping few columns and add few columns.

So I created a temporary table `tmp_financial_details` from `rails generate migration` command and copied all `financial_details` table data into it.

Now I want to get all the `tmp_financial_details` data and store it to `financial_details` table. Something like this,

```
TmpFinancialDetail.all.each do |t|
   f = FinancialDetail.new()
   f.something =   t.someting * abc()
   f.save
end
```

Since I created `tmp_financial_details` table without any model, how can process it with an ActiveRecord instance object?

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with your databases in rails without making classes.  For example, the following will load an array of hashes corresponding to the data, which might be just as useful for you when moving data between tables:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select * from tmp_financial_details")
```

Comment: this one looks great, I tried with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and it returns `Mysql::Result` which is hard to process. But `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` returns array of hashes which can be processed easily. Thanks

Comment: This will not return `ActiveRecord` Objects

Comment: @shiva, i know, but i don't think he actually needs to use ActiveRecord objects, even though he asked how to in the question.  He just needs to get at the data to solve his problem.

Comment: @arivarasan - you should look in an API doc, it has all sorts of useful info, including the difference between .execute and .select_all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Or you can create a temp model and use it

```
class TmpFinancialDetail < FinancialDetail
 set_table_name :tmp_financial_details
end

 TmpFinancialDetail.all.each do |t|
   f = FinancialDetail.new()
   f.something =   t.someting * abc()
   f.save
 end
```

**Note:** Make sure you inherit `TmpFinancialDetail < FinancialDetail`

Comment: `@temp_store = FinancialDetail.all` will get records from `tmp_financial_details` table and again `f = FinancialDetail.new() .. f.save` stores record to the same table `tmp_financial_details`

Comment: have you given `FinancialDetail.table_name = "financial_details"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just define the class in your script, no need to have it in a separate file. That is just one line and it provides all the magic.

```
class TmpFinancialDetail < ActiveRecord::Base; end

TmpFinancialDetail.find_each do |t|
  FinancialDetail.create(:something => t.something * abc)
end
```